# Missing V9 Menu: File -> New -> FreeCDF

Tags: version-9, cdf-format

I can run CDFs fine, and can export Notebooks as CDFs. But the `File -> New` menu does not contain a `FreeCDF` option, just the `Package` and `Text File` options. What am I missing? M9.0.1.0 on Mac OS X Mavericks.

Comment: Well, OK, but the CDF documentation ("Create CDF" in MMA docs) clearly shows an option to create a new CDF, in a screenshot. I guess you are right, though, but how can the docs be so wrong?

Comment: @Kuba Sure. Look at https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/howto/CreateAComputableDocumentFormatFile.html.

Comment: @Kuba glad I'm not the only one.

Comment: I think the CDF option was there in version 8 but it seems to have been removed in v9.

Comment: @SimonWoods would you mind posting your comment as an answer? Otherwise I'll write my own answer and accept it.

Comment: The CDF option [was there in v8](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7YPTv.png).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *File / New / FreeCDF* menu option was introduced in version 8 but was withdrawn in version 9.  The v9 documentation appears to be out of date.

The new workflow is as follows:

- create a regular notebook
- use the new *File / CDF Preview / CDF Player* or *File / CDF Preview / Player Pro* menu options to view and test the notebook as a CDF
- once satisfied with the functionality of the notebook, save the notebook using either *File / CDF Export* or *File / Save As... / Save As Type / CDF*

The provisional version 10 documentation appears to have been [partially updated](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/CreateAComputableDocumentFormatFile.html).  It does not mention the *CDF Preview* option, and there are still some [lingering pages](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/FreeCDF.html) that discuss the non-existent FreeCDF option.